# yo polymer is generating polyer 0.4.0 version

Tags: polymer

When I execute `yo polymer` this is what I get in my bower.json.

`{
  "name": "flatiron2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "core-elements": "Polymer/core-elements#^0.4.0",
    "paper-elements": "Polymer/paper-elements#^0.4.0",
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^0.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "polymer-test-tools": "Polymer/polymer-test-tools#^0.4.0"
  }
}`

How do I get the latest version of the polymer using yo.

I can see that https://github.com/yeoman/generator-polymer has been updated to use polymer 0.5 but how do I update to the latest generator on my mac machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is an upgraded generator available...yet.

This does not update the generator, but it will "upgrade" your generated code to polymers most recent version, as of now. So, this is a workaround, but it works, and does what you need:

1. Completely delete bower_components folder, so you get a clean start.
2. Make the following changes to your `bower.json` file:

   ```
   "dependencies": {
     "core-elements": "Polymer/core-elements#^0.5.1",
     "paper-elements": "Polymer/paper-elements#^0.5.1",
     "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^0.5.1"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
     "polymer-test-tools": "Polymer/polymer-test-tools#^0.5.1"
   },
   ```
3. run `bower install` from the command line where your `bower.json` file is located.
4. Change the line in your `app/index.html` file from:

   ```
   <script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
   ```

   to

   ```
   <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
   ```

They have renamed the `platform.js` file to `webcomponents.js`

5. run `grunt server` and enjoy.

That should do it, you should be running the most current version of Polymer.